# Write $5$ and $6+8i$ as products of irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

> Write $5$ and $6+8i$ as products of irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I am not sure how to do $5$. Do I assume $5=\alpha \beta$, and so $v(\alpha\beta)=v(\alpha)v(\beta)=5$. Then since $5\equiv 1$ (mod $4$), how do I find two non-associate irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that equal $5$?

For $6+8i$, what I did was factor out $2$. Then $2(3+4i)=(1+i)(1-i)\alpha\beta$. Then $v(\alpha\beta) = 25$ or $\alpha = \beta = 5$. However, since $5\equiv 1$ (mod $4$), I am again stuck on the dilemma where I cannot find two non-associate irreducible elements that equal $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, here's the mistake: $v(5)\neq 5$, $v(5)=25$. Now, $5=1+4 = 1^2+2^2 = (1+2i)(1-2i)$. Similarly $2 = 1^2 + 1^2 = (1+i)(1-i)$. Can you finish now?

Comment: Oh I see now! I do understand that $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$ now. For $6+8i$, I got $6+8i=(1+i)(1-i)(1+2i)^{2}(1-2i)^{2}$ ...Is this correct though?

Comment: @numericalorange, it's not correct. What you have to use for $3+4i$ (since it's of norm $25$) is what I wrote: $5=1^2+2^2$. So $3+4i = (\pm 1 \pm 2i)(\pm 1\pm 2i)$ or $(\pm 2 \pm i)(\pm 2\pm i)$, or a mix of those two (however, these differ by unit $i$, so it's not essential difference). You need to check which combination works.

Comment: Are conjugates associate elements? Is there any efficient way to choose the right combination of factors?

Comment: @numericalorange, not in general. But you know what gives $5$ (and $-5$ also), so eliminate those. I mean, in the end it's just $\pm 1\pm 2i\pm 2i\pm 4i^2$. Not that hard to come up with what works.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and helping me understand in a clear way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $N(\alpha\beta)$, which I assume is $v$ in your case, is 25 not 5 as $N(\alpha\beta) = N(5) = 5^2$.

Then, $25 = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$ and the only way to factor is when both norms equal 5. 
Can you go on from here?